# Python Google API build

Tags: python, html, mysql

I've been trying to upload a block of html into a MySQL table and am getting an error message but it's a bit confusing as far as where the problem is exactly. The code is as follows (this isn't all the code, just the conflict area):

```
from mysql import connector
import time

def send(self, config, query, queryData):
    cnx = connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, queryData)
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

#this grabs the list of the succesfulyCapturedPackages and uploads to the wp_posts table.
def upload(self):
    txtdate = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    for pkg in self.succesfullyCaptured:
        filename = pkg + ".html"
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            package_post = f.read()
        current_timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        trimmed_package_name = pkg.lower()
        trimmed_package_name = trimmed_package_name.replace(" ","-")
        tup = self.fetch(self.configExternalDB,"SELECT MAX(ID) from wp_posts")
        webURL = "http://www.AWORDPRESSSITE.com/?p=" + str(int(tup[0][0]) + 1)
        package_post = connector.conversion.MySQLConverter().escape(package_post)

        add_pkg_data = ("INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date,"
            "post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_status,"
            "comment_status, ping_status, post_name, "
            "post_modified, post_modified_gmt, "
            "post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type, "
            "comment_count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, "
            "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)")

        data_pkg = (1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, package_post, 
            pkg, 'draft', 'open', 'open', trimmed_package_name, 
            current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 0, webURL, 0, 'post', 0)

        self.send(self.configExternalDB , add_pkg_data, data_pkg)
```

Now what I'm getting is the following:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

BTW the HTML blocks I'm trying to capture look somewhat like this:

```html
<h5><span lang=\"ES-MX\"> text text text $ 1000  USD +  755.00 text text días</span></h5>\n<h6><span lang=\"ES-MX\">Text: Text / Text / Text / Text</span></h6>\n<!--more--><span style=\"font-weight: 600; color: #222222;\">[google-map-v3 shortcodeid=\"TO_BE_GENERATED\" width=\"100%\" height=\"350\" zoom=\"12\" maptype=\"roadmap\" mapalign=\"center\" directionhint=\"false\" language=\"default\" poweredby=\"false\" maptypecontrol=\"true\" pancontrol=\"true\" zoomcontrol=\"true\" scalecontrol=\"true\" streetviewcontrol=\"true\" scrollwheelcontrol=\"false\" draggable=\"true\" tiltfourtyfive=\"false\" enablegeolocationmarker=\"false\" enablemarkerclustering=\"false\" addmarkermashup=\"false\" addmarkermashupbubble=\"false\" addmarkerlist=\" Buenos Aires{}1-default.png|Iguazu{}1-default.png|Bariloche{}1-default.png|Santiago{}1-default.png|\" bubbleautopan=\"true\" distanceunits=\"miles\" showbike=\"false\" showtraffic=\"false\" showpanoramio=\"false\"]</span>\n<h2>TEXT</h2>\n<address>*TEXT</address>\n
```

... Except bigger (more html text).

So what I'm not sure of at this point is if the HTML characters are not being escaped correctly or if I'm missing something somewhere.

As always, help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    add_pkg_data = ("INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date,"
        "post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_status,"
        "comment_status, ping_status, post_name, "
        "post_modified, post_modified_gmt, "
        "post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type, "
        "comment_count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, "
        "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
```

Not sure you need the comma after the final `%s`.

Comment: This worked! Hahaha, it's really late here... Thanks a lot. :)